# How we can ROLLBACK the Transaction in WSO2DSS or WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i am inserting no of tables at a time using WSO2dss and Wso2 ESB . those are dependent tables how we can ROLLBACK if one transaction failed.my issue is i am inserting EMP1,EMP2,EMP3
my data inserted properly in EMP1 and EMP2 error occured in while inserting in EMP3 how i can do this using WSO2 ..in Oracle we has NONXAENABLEDS

```
<sequence>
                  <payloadFactory>
                     <format>
                        <p:insert_emp2_operation xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                           <xs:e_device xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:e_device>
                           <xs:e_amount xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">5000</xs:e_amount>
                           <xs:e_no xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">450</xs:e_no>
                        </p:insert_emp2_operation>
                     </format>
                     <args>
                        <arg expression="//e_device/text()"/>
                     </args>
                  </payloadFactory>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://192.168.1.201:9764/services/emp2_DataService/" format="soap11"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </sequence>
            </target>
```

as same like in some other tables How i Can Rollback this all

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable transactions with rollback using WSO2 DSS itself, you can use the following steps.
If your related tables are in the same database then you can use [boxcarring feature](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Boxcarring+Sample) in WSO2 data services server, where you can enable boxcarring at the data service creation level. If your tables are distributed among different databases then you can use [distributed transaction feature](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Distributed+Transactions+Sample). However, once you enable both these features you need to change your proxy services accordingly. You can check the following [blog](http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-call-multiple-soap-operations.html) for more details on how to call the data service when distributed transaction/ boxcarring is enabled using WSO2 ESB.

Comment: i followed u r blog but its not working  please go through this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195319/how-we-can-rollback-the-transaction-in-wso2dss-or-wso2esb